# I have a sample text file and I want my data to be an array and have a index

Tags: arrays, laravel

This is my code for reading a text file. I'm using Laravel framework. I'm new at Laravel.

```
public function textfile(Request $request){
    $test = 'sample_remote_tempfile.txt';
    $content = Storage::get('upload/'.$test);
    $pieces = explode(",", $content);
    foreach ($pieces as $key => $line) {

    }
}
```

I want my result to become like this

```
[{ 
  mac_address: b8:27:eb:a2:66:08,
  timestamps :  1538219012280,
  water_level: 16.388515,120
   etc
}]
```

Comment: Add file's original content structure to the question.

Answer (score -2):

You should try this:

```
public function textfile(Request $request){
    $test = 'sample_remote_tempfile.txt';
    $content = Storage::get('upload/'.$test);
    $pieces = file($content, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    foreach ($pieces as $key => $line) {
      }
   }
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--


ErrorException: file(b8:27:eb:a2:66:08,1538219012280,16.388515,120.729569,24.765,64.89,1001.23,3.61,18.64,1.12,12.11,0
b8:27:eb:a2:66:08,1538219012280,16.388515,120.729569,24.765,64.89,1001.23,3.61,18.64,1.12,12.11,0): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in file